# UICollectionView - correct way to customize item layout based on data?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm still new to UICollectionView, so I need help understanding how to properly link layout and data. Let's say I'm using a basic flow layout (or its subclass) with a single column of items in sections. Depending on the content of the section, I want to position the header either left or right.

Where should that connection between the layout attributes for the header and my data happen? I can't seem  to connect the dots..

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.objc.io/issue-3/collection-view-layouts.html

> There are two general types of collection view layouts:
>
> Layouts whose computations are independent of the content. This is the “simple” case you know from UITableView and UICollectionViewFlowLayout. The position and appearance of each cell does not depend on the content it displays but on its order in the list of all cells. Consider the default flow layout as an example. Each cell is positioned next to its predecessor (or at the beginning of the next line if there is no space left). The layout object does not need to access the actual data to compute the layout.
>
> Layouts that need to do content-dependent computations. Our calendar view is an example of this type. It requires the layout object to ask the collection view’s data source directly for the start and end dates of the events it is supposed to display. In many cases, the layout object not only requires data about the currently visible cells but needs some information from all records in order to determine which cells are currently visible in the first place.
>
> In our calendar example, the layout object – if asked for the attributes of the cells inside a certain rectangle – must iterate over all events provided by the data source to determine which ones lie in the requested time window. Contrast this with a flow layout where some relatively simple and data-source-independent math is sufficient to compute the index paths of the cells that lie in a certain rectangle (assuming that all cells in the grid have the same size).
>
> Having a content-dependent layout is a strong indication that you will need to write your own custom layout class and won’t get by with customizing UICollectionViewFlowLayout. So that’s exactly what we are going to do.
>
> The documentation for UICollectionViewLayout lists the methods that subclasses should override.

I suggest you to have a read in there and have a look at their calendar example.